# convergence of a sequence of polynomials.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Let $\{P_n\}$ be a sequence of polynomials of degree $\leq n$. If $\{P_n\}$ convergences pointwise (to some function, say $f(x)$) on $[0,1]$, then, prove that $\{P_n\}$ convergences uniformly to $f$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are there any results you have already seen, that might be helpful?

Comment: Is there a question there? I don't see any question.

Comment: Convergent in what sense? Make this clear please.

Answer (score 0):

The space $L_m$ of polynomials of degree $<m+1$ is a finite dimensional vector space, if $P_n$ converges, it is a Cauchy sequence in $L_m$, remark that all norms are equivalent in $L_m$, you can take the norm $\|a_0+...+a_{m-1}x^{-1}\|=sup(|a_i|)_{i=1,..,m-1}$, so it is Cauchy for this norm, so the coefficients converge and $P_n$ converges towards a polynomial.